# Why can't I animate my characther's face while the rest of the body is moving?

Tags: animation

I know how to use the timeline; I can set keyframes and have characters move; but when I try to make keyframes with anything face-related, if I move/rotate/scale it in the second keyframe, that is the position/rotation/scale it has for the whole animation. I can edit the face, but I can't make it change *during* the animation. This means no blinking, no talking, no looking around... it's really annoying.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg0sf5cpsdbswg5/SomeIdiotsProblem.zip?dl=0

Comment: Post you .blend so it's easier to debug this. It seems like your rig is just broken

Comment: It isn't my own rig I'm using, and it happens with every rig I try, not just one.

Comment: Ok... Did you animate the face _after_ the rest of the body? When you keyframed the body did you do it with everything selected?

Comment: I did animate the face after the body. And I didn't animate the body parts with everything selected.

Comment: Still, post your .blend

Comment: Ok, I posted it.